# Opening Foxx API to local network

Tags: server, arangodb, foxx

I have setup serverend points they work for the web interface fine but the api endpoint for my for app do not even give a error and does not time out.
I have tried turn the app to production mode in the web interfaces no joy.
I look at the doc for server setup but can find any thing to help.

So I would think their is configure issue where should I look?

On localhost ever thing works.
On remote host where using 168.192.0.15:8530 only web interface works not my api form either curl or may app

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what URL you are trying to access, from which server (localhost or different server) you are trying to access the app, and whether or not accessing the web interface from that same server works? Additionally, any information on what `--server.endpoint` configuration you used will help, on whether your server requires authentication, uses SSL, and what the result of calling the target URL via curl will produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have learn the issue is the api endpoint url is not the same on localhost at their are from outside. Example:

```
curl -X GET --dump -  http://localhost:8529/broad/broad/login
curl -X GET --dump - http://192.168.0.15:8530/_db/_system/broad/broad/login
```

Comment: Are you saying this issue is solved now? I am sorry I don't understand what the solution was. Could you elaborate? Apart from that, if your answers answers your question, I think you can accept it yourself so it's marked closed.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information I can only guess what the problem is, but I'll try:

The default `--server.endpoint` configuration value for an ArangoDB server is `tcp://127.0.0.1:8529`. That means you will be able to access it from the local machine but not from other hosts.

To make the server respond to HTTP requests originated from other hosts, you will need to use an endpoint that includes the server's IP address as used in your network, e.g. `tcp://192.168.173.13:8529` and restart it with the adjusted configuration.

If that's not working either, can you trying calling the target URL from another server via *curl* and check the server's HTTP response code. This might reveal the source of the problem, too. Note that you should invoke *curl* with the option `--dump -` to see the HTTP response code. For example:

```
curl -X GET --dump - http://192.168.173.13:8529/your/app
```

If that is not producing any results (i.e. no response at all), you might have a firewall in between that blocks requests. Probably you need to allow access on the port ArangoDB uses (`8529` by default and used in my example).

Comment: So the arango web interface aka and collections and so on work find. But the api end points don't work with that ip 168.192.0.15:8530 will show browser but when put that before /broad/broad/ping form and my sp web app or curl all get is time out

Comment: curl -X GET --dump - http://168.192.0.15:8530/broad/broad/login
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 168.192.0.15 port 8530: Connection timed out                   dump did not change anything it still times out but my web interface still works fine form anther computer